# mapbox gl change icon color

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way to change a mapbox-gl-js icon-image color?

This code taken from https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/ won't change the marker color to red

```javascript
map.addLayer({
    "id": "markers",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "markers",
    "layout": {
        "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}-15",
        "text-field": "{title}",
        "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
        "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
        "text-anchor": "top"
    },
    "paint": {
        "text-size": 12,
        "icon-color" : "#ff0000"
    }
});
```

I've tried all the options listed in the official documentation

Comment: Same issue can't figure it out also, maybe create a ticket on github?

Comment: lol I just realised you did haha

Answer (score 11):

The Problem is MapBox only allows you to color icons which are in the SDF *(signed distance function)* format.

> [icon-color](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-symbol-icon-color)
>   The color of the icon. This can only be used with sdf icons.

[Here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-style-spec/issues/97#issuecomment-159868758) is a small documentation about it. Like the GitHub post says it's limited for only **one color**. Getting a sdf file out of a png file is pretty easy in MapBox.

The documentation of the [addImage](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addimage) function tells you that you can add an optional options paramater which can contain sdf and pixelRatio.

So all you have to do is something like this:

```
        map.loadImage(imageURL, function(error0, image0) {
            if (error0) throw error0;
            map.addImage("image", image0, {
                "sdf": "true"
            });

            map.addLayer({
                "id": "Layer1",
                "type": "symbol",
                "source": "places",
                "layout": {
                    "icon-image": "image",
                    "icon-allow-overlap": true,
                },
                "paint": {
                    "icon-color": "#00ff00",
                    "icon-halo-color": "#fff",
                    "icon-halo-width": 2
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

I found a answer. You need sdf icons specifically for it to work.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1594

`Unfortunately we don't have a turnkey solution for generating sdf icons but you can see an example of how its done in the maki project`

<strike>https://github.com/mapbox/maki/blob/mb-pages/sdf-render.js</strike>

**Updated by @yurik:** The above link no longer works, probably refers to https://github.com/mapbox/maki/blob/b0060646e28507037e71edf049a17fab470a0080/sdf-render.js

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/161

Answer (score 3):

You could also use your own pre-colored external icons (or generate colored ones on the fly) as `icon-image` if you use `map.loadImage()` and `map.addImage()` first.

Examples:

[Add an icon to the map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/)

[Add a generated icon to the map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image-generated/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change icon color of png you just have to add this additional input `sdf: true` while adding an image.

And also set
paint property addlayer

```
"paint": {
   "icon-color": "#00ff00",
   "icon-halo-color": "#fff",
   "icon-halo-width": 2
   }

this.map.addImage("Id", iconUrl, { sdf: true });
```